# Partition empty when connection iPhone 7 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, file-sharing, iphone

[image]

I'm trying to connect the iPhone 7 to Ubuntu 16.04. Apparently it has no problem mounting the device, but the partition seems to be empty, there are no folders and I can't access my photos or transfer music. I did give it permission to trust the computer in the iPhone.

Comment: You can't transfer files to an iDevice from Linux, unfortunately. For whatever reason, Apple makes you use iTunes, which is not available for Linux. And no, it doesn't work through WINE either.

Comment: So, can't we import/sync music/photos between ubuntu and iphone ?

Comment: @AndroidDev that is not true. you can (only photos and albums). but sometimes this happens like in the screenshot. please be sure, then write a comment.